# WCF Service not loading drop down

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, iis, cascadingdropdown

I have a wcf service used to populate cascading drop down list in a ASPX page in IIS 7.  The drop down list gets thousands of empty option tags but no data.  The service does not throw an error.  The entire solution runs in IDE on desktop but the service is not working correctly when deployed on IIS.  I suspect it is an IIS issue but can not identify it.

```
&lt;snippet from aspx page&gt;
&lt;asp:DropDownList ID="ddCommercialServicesSiteName" runat="server" Width="150"&gt;&lt;/asp:DropDownList&gt;
&lt;ajaxToolkit:CascadingDropDown 
    ID="cddCommercialServicesSiteName" TargetControlID="ddCommercialServicesSiteName" 
    PromptText="Select" PromptValue=""   Category="siteID" 
    ServicePath="~/ServiceDropDown.svc" ServiceMethod="GetCommercialSites"
    LoadingText ="Loading..."  runat="server"/&gt;


&lt;!-- ServiceDropDown.svc code  --&gt;
&lt;%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="ReportDashboard.ServiceDropDown" CodeBehind="ServiceDropDown.svc.cs" %&gt;
```

public List GetCommercialSites(string knownCategoryValues, string contextKey)

{
    List sites = new List();

```
if (contextKey == null)
```

{

```
return sites;
```

}
    string query = @"select DISTINCT  ContactName AS Site , id from sites";

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);

using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))

{
con.Open();

cmd.Connection = con;

cmd.Parameters.Add("@account", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = contextKey.ToString();

using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())

{

    while (reader.Read())

    {

        sites.Add(new CascadingDropDownNameValue
        {
            name = reader[0].ToString(),
            value = reader[1].ToString(),
        });

    }

    reader.Close();

    con.Close();

}
```

}

```
return sites;
```

}

Comment: I don't think it has to do with your problem, but what is the @account parameter for? It doesn't seem to be used by your query. As far as your question, you're saying the sites.Add is being called thousands of times, but the name and value is blank each time? Have you debugged it to see what's being returned by the query?

Comment: An error when formatting.  I lost the query where clause.  Should have been "where account = @account.

Comment: If I step through the function it returns the appropriate number if items, say 5.  But when the page is rendered the drop down list had about 2300 blank option tags.  So something between the hand off of the list to asp engine but I do not know how to debug that on the server.

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach to retrieve values from the Reader.

```
List<MyModelClass> result = new List<MyModelClass>();



while (reader.Read())

{

            object[] values = new object[3];

            reader.GetValues(values);



            MyModelClass model = new MyModelClass();



            model.ID = values[0].ToString();

            model.ValueProperty = values[1].ToString();

            model.ValueProperty2 = values[2].ToString();



            result.Add(model);

}
```

In your View/aspx run a jQuery to populate your dropdown,

```
                            $("#dropdown").change(function () {

                                            dropdown.append($("<option></option>").val("").html("Please wait ..."));



                                            $.ajax({

                                                            url: "/api/CascadingData/GetSomeData/",

                                                            type: "GET",

                                                            dataType: "json",

                                                            data: { Id: Id },

                                                            success: function (d) {

                                                                            dropdown.empty(); // Clear the list, including the please wait option

                                                                            dropdown.append($("<option></option>").val('').html("Select an option..."));

                                                                            $.each(d, function (i, ModelObject) {

                                                                                            dropdown.append($("<option></option>").val(ModelObject.Name).html(ModelObject.Value));

                                                                            });

                                                            },

                                                            error: function () {

                                                                            alert("Error in $('#dropdown').change!");

                                                            }

                                            });

                            }
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion    This does not work.  The ajaxToolkit:CascadingDropDown is expecting a list.  I did test this method and interesting enough the drop down list is populated with the correct number of option tags but they appear as empty options.    <option value=""> </option>    The issue is in the IDE it works.  On the server it does not.

Comment: I modified my answer above. Use the list of your model classes and populate the drop down with jQuery